# How to create a contextual array in JS

Tags: javascript, c#

In c#, adding new values is very easy and non-confusing to do, as an example, this is what i normally do in c#:

```
namespace Sup
{

public class Pizza
{
    public List<Pepperoni> PepperoniList { get; set; }
    public List<Cheese> CheeseList { get; set; }
    public List<Crust> CrustList { get; set; }
    public List<Sauce> SauceList { get; set; }
}

public class Pepperoni
{
    public string cost { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Cheese
{
    public string cost { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Crust
{
    public string cost { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Sauce
{
    public string cost { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
}


public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pizza p = new Pizza()
                      {
                          PepperoniList = new List<Pepperoni>(),
                          CheeseList = new List<Cheese>(),
                          CrustList = new List<Crust>(),
                          SauceList = new List<Sauce>()
                      };

        p.PepperoniList.Add(new Pepperoni() {cost = "5.00", quantity = "1"});
        p.CheeseList.Add(new Cheese() {cost = "", quantity = ""});
        p.CrustList.Add(new Crust() {cost = "", quantity = ""});
        p.SauceList.Add(new Sauce() {cost = "", quantity = ""});


Console.WriteLine(p.PepperoniList[0].cost);
    }



}
}
```

As you can see when i add new values to my classes i dont take a second look at what im doing, it's easy to add new values AND to display them.

However, in JS it's another story, this is what im currently working on in JS:

```
var pepperoni= [];
pepperoni.push([["cost"], ["quantity"]]);

console.log(pepperoni[0][0]);
```

As you can see this form of adding/displaying the value does not look easy to read and work with, i need something like the c# example, what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be directly translated into JavaScript:

```
class Pizza {
    constructor(){
        this.pepperoniList = [];
        // add more if you want
    }
}

class Pepperoni {
    constructor(cost, quantity){
        this.cost = cost;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}

var p = new Pizza();
p.pepperoniList.push(new Pepperoni(5, 1));    // add a new Pepperoni object
```

Comment: i get an error using this code, it says 'ECMAScript 2015 feature.  Your current language level is: ECMAScript 5'

Comment: @eBay The `class` syntax is introduced in ES6 (ES2015). You can either use the ES5 syntax for creating classes, or use a transpiler (recommended). Googling your warning message hints that you are using ReSharper. You can change the language level if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript solution, you're adding an array with two arrays, not an object. Just add an object to get the same result as in C#:

```
var pepperoni = [];
pepperoni.push({ cost: 5.0, quantity: 1 });

console.log(pepperoni[0]); // prints { cost: 5.0, quantity: 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```js
class Ingredient {
  constructor(cost, quantity) {
    this.cost = cost;
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }
}

class Pepperoni extends Ingredient {

}

class Cheese extends Ingredient {

}

class Crust extends Ingredient {

}

class Sauce extends Ingredient {

}

class Pizza {
  constructor(crust, sauce, cheese, pepperoni) {
    this.crust = crust;
    this.sauce = sauce;
    this.cheese = cheese;
    this.pepperoni = pepperoni;
  }
}

const pizza = new Pizza(new Crust(5, 1), new Sauce(2, 1), new Cheese(3, 1), new Pepperoni(2, 1));
console.log(pizza);
```